# Why OS Windows does not boot after disk disconnected?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, hard-drive, boot

I have problem with booting from Mandriva linux boot menu to Windows. I previously used two disks: one with Windows and one with Mandriva and booting worked. However when I removed the disk with Mandriva and then installed Mandriva on the disk with Windows, so I can see Mandriva menu, but after I choose Windows then it halts. To describe my problem, I will write down the old configuration and then the new configuration.

**Old** configuration HW:
1) primary master SATA: disk SATA 500 GB with Mandriva linux on sda3
grub menu.lst contains:

```
title sata XP
 unhide (hd0,0)
 hide (hd0,1)
rootnoverify (hd0,0)
chainloader +1
makeactive
savedefault
```

2) secondary slave IDE: disk ATA 150 GB with jumper on position "Master with slave"
partition one contains:

```
NTDETECT.COM
CONFIG.SYS
IO.SYS
MSDOS.SYS
ntldr
boot.ini
```

boot.ini:

```
 [boot loader]
    timeout=3
    default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
    [operating systems]
    multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="SATA XP1" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
    c:\mandriva.bin="Mandriva menu"
```

3)  Booting sequence in BIOS is hdd1 and then hdd0

The **new** configuration:
1) primary master ATA:  disk ATA 150 GB with NO jumper indicating that the disk is single and master. 
sda1 contains windows as described above (same partition).
sda3 contains linux
grub menu.lst contains:

```
title Windows XP1 6GB
root (hd0,0)
makeactive
chainloader +1
```

From the above, should be clear that in the old configuration, the MBR on sda1 as SATA was read first. Then from the grub menu.lst I choose Windows and the Windows booter is found on first partition. Then Windows runs.

Now when I disconnect the SATA, and remove the jumper from ATA, booting menu from Mandriva on ATA is showed. I choose Windows and I see blue window with message that I should check the configuration of disk or check disk for errors with chkdsk /F. error: STOP: 0x0000007B (0xF889E528, 0xC0000034, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)

Question:
Can you help me what to do to fix the Windows boot problem?

Comment: Well, 0x7b means “Inaccessible Boot Device”, meaning Windows could not continue to access the Windows partition after switching to direct access (from BIOS access)—typically a missing driver. Still, I couldn’t quite wrap my head around your old and new configurations, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the disk that you are removing very likely has Windows installed on it, or has the boot loader on it that windows requires in order to start.

typically HDD0 is the primary boot device, and HDD1 is the next drive. When you install windows, it automatically puts it's boot loader on drive 0, even if drive 0 is not the selected boot device. If you're removing drive 0, then you are removing the bootable core of windows, thus preventing Windows from being able to start.

It sounds to me that if you want to use this new configuration, you will have to completely reinstall both operating systems, while you have this configuration active.

Comment: It is one possibility. The other one could be that the partition which I was trying to boot from was hidden. I changed computer and installed Windows to new disk.